# How do I extract only the content from this webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying out webscraping using BeautifulSoup.

I only want extract the content from this webpage basically everything from Barry Kripke without all the headers..etc.
https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Barry_Kripke

I tried this, but it doesn't give me what I want

```
quote = 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Barry_Kripke'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', quote)

if r.status == 200:
  page = r.data
  print('Type of the variable \'page\':', page.__class__.__name__)
  print('Page Retrieved. Request Status: %d, Page Size: %d' % (r.status, len(page)))
else:
  print('Some problem occurred. Request Status: %s' % r.status)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print('Type of the variable \'soup\':', soup.__class__.__name__)

print(soup.prettify()[:1000])

article_tag = 'p'
article = soup.find_all(article_tag)[0]
print(f'Type of the variable "article":{article.__class__.__name__}')

article.text
```

The output I get is below, which is just the first paragraph

[image: what I get]

What I want is this:
[image: what I want]

Next I tried to get all the links, but that didn't work either - I got only 2 links:

```
for t in article.find_all('a'):
    print(t)
```

[image]

Please can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only grab and print out the 1st `<p>` tag with `article = soup.find_all(article_tag)[0]`

You need to go through all the `<p>` tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Barry_Kripke'
r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code == 200:
  page = r.text
  print('Type of the variable \'page\':', page.__class__.__name__)
  print('Page Retrieved. Request Status: %d, Page Size: %d' % (r.status_code, len(page)))
else:
  print('Some problem occurred. Request Status: %s' % r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print('Type of the variable \'soup\':', soup.__class__.__name__)

print(soup.prettify()[:1000])

article_tag = 'p'
articles = soup.find_all(article_tag)

for p in articles:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This worked, but when I use print(f'Type of the variable "article":{article.__class__.__name__}') it outputs ResultSet and not Tag....why is that?                                                             
Also, when I further want to get all the links in the content I get an error (ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?). I used the following: tag = 'a'
tag_list = [t.get('href') for t in articles.find_all(tag)]
tag_list

Comment: I don’t have ‘article’ variable in my code at all, so that has nothing to do with the solution I provided. And  for the 2nd bit, you are not constructin the list comprehension correctly.  I will/can address these issues, but will not do it here in the comments. Your original question has been answered. The etiquette is to Accept the solution as it answers your original post, and if by answering your question new errors/bugs arise, then ask in a new question, do not continue to add additional questions and requirements beyond the scope of the original post.