# How to avoid attribute error while extracting links from articles?

Tags: python, html, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying my hand at webscraping using `BeautifulSoup`.

I had posted this before here, but I was not very clear as to what I wanted, so it only partially answers my issue.
[How do I extract only the content from this webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488213/how-do-i-extract-only-the-content-from-this-webpage/73488548?noredirect=1#comment129817276_73488548)

I want to extract the content from the webpage and then extract all the links from the output. Please can someone help me understand where I am going wrong.

This is what I have after updating my previous code with the answer provided in the link above.

```
# Define the content to retrieve (webpage's URL)
quote_page = 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Barry_Kripke'

# Retrieve the page
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', quote_page)

if r.status == 200:
    page = r.data
    print(f'Type of Variable "page": {page.__class__.__name__}')
    print(f'Page Retrieved. Request Status: {r.status}, Page Size:{len(page)}')
else:
    print(f'Some problem occured. Request status: {r.status}')

# Convert the stream of bytes into a BeautifulSoup representation
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(f'Type of variable "soup": {soup.__class__.__name__}')

# Check the content
print(f'{soup. Prettify()[:1000]}')

# Check the HTML's Title
print(f'Title tag: {soup.title}')
print(f'Title text: {soup.title.string}')

# Find the main content
article_tag = 'p'
articles = soup.find_all(article_tag)
print(f'Type of the variable "article":{article.__class__.__name__}')

for p in articles:
    print (p.text)
```

I then used the code below to get all the links, but get an error

```
# Find the links in the text
# identify the type of tag to retrieve
tag = 'a'

# create a list with the links from the `<a>` tag
tag_list = [t.get('href') for t in articles.find_all(tag)]
tag_list
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is cause `articles` is a `ResultSet` of `soup.find_all(article_tag)` what you can check with `type(articles)`

To get your goal you have to iterate `articles` first - So simply add an additional `for-loop` to your `list comprehension`:

```
[t.get('href') for article in articles for t in article.find_all(tag)]
```

In addition you may should use a `set comprehension` to avoid duplicates and also concat paths with base url:

```
list(set(t.get('href') if t.get('href').startswith('http') else 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com'+t.get('href') for article in articles for t in article.find_all(tag)))
```

Output:

```
['https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Killer_Robot_Instability',
 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Rajesh_Koothrappali',
 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Bernadette_Rostenkowski-Wolowitz',
 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Valentino_Submergence',
 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beta_Test_Initiation',
 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Season_2',
 'https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Dr._Pemberton',...]
```